# Why am I getting a deadlock in this producer-consumer in Java using locks and conditions?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I am a newbie to Java and I am trying to learn Java concurrency. I have written a simple code for the producer-consumer problem (with single producer and consumer). There seems to be a deadlock because the consumer is not notified when data is available. Can anyone please review the code?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

class ThreadFactory implements Runnable{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Thread prThread;
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
    final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
    final int CAPACITY = 10;

    public enum Role{
    PRODUCER,
    CONSUMER
    };

    Role role;
    public int i = 0;

    private void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true){
            lock.lock();
            try{
                while(list.size()  == CAPACITY){
                    System.out.println("List is full to its CAPACITY, waiting");
                    notEmpty.await();
                }
                String str = "Data " + i++;
                System.out.println("Putting " + str + " to list");
                list.add(str);
                notFull.signalAll();
            }
            finally{
                lock.unlock();
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

    private void consume() throws InterruptedException{
        while(true){
            lock.lock();
            try{
                while(list.size() == 0){
                    System.out.println("List is empty, waiting");
                    notFull.await();
                }
                String str = list.remove(list.size()-1);
                System.out.println("Popping " + str + " from list");
                notEmpty.signal();
            }
            finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Starting thread " + prThread.getName());
        try{
            if(role == Role.PRODUCER){
                produce();
            }           
            else if(role == Role.CONSUMER){
                consume();
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
        }
    }

    public ThreadFactory(List<String> l, int role, String name){
        this.list = l;
        prThread = new Thread(this, name);
        if(role == 0)
            this.role = Role.PRODUCER;
        else
            this.role = Role.CONSUMER;
        prThread.start();
    }
}

public class ProducerConsumer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        ThreadFactory c = new ThreadFactory(l,1, "Consumer");
        ThreadFactory p = new ThreadFactory(l,0, "Producer");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the lock is not released when either consumer or producer acquires a lock and they wait for their condition to occur. So, surround the code notEmpty.await(); and notFull.await(); by lock.unlock() and lock.lock().

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. The issue was same as told by @Nathan. The threads had their own lock instances. I made the lock and conditions static and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a deadlock, The lock is an instance member of each class, where each runnable instance creates its own lock. Your producer and consumer are using their own locks so they're not seeing each other's signals and they wait forever. They should be using the same lock.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nathan for the brilliant catch. I just made the lock and condition variable static and everything worked. Many thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure of what is happening may be it because you are running both the *consume()* and *produce()* methods in the method *run()* of the class *ThreadFactory*.

What I will do is create a class for the Consumer and another for the Producer, with both classes extending the class Thread. Then I will call the consume() and producer() in the run() of their respective classes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class ThreadFactory {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();
    final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
    final int CAPACITY = 10;

    public int i = 0;

    class Producer extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (list.size() == CAPACITY) {
                    System.out.println("List is full to its CAPACITY, producer waiting");
                    notFull.await();
                }
                if (i == CAPACITY) i=0;
                String str = "Data " + i++;
                System.out.println("Putting " + str + " to list of size "+list.size());
                list.add(str);
                if (list.size() ==1 )
                    notEmpty.signal();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

    private void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (list.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("List is empty, consumer waiting");
                    notEmpty.await();
                }
                String str = list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                System.out.println("Popping " + str + " from list of size "+list.size());
                if (list.size() ==CAPACITY-1 )
                    notFull.signal();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public ThreadFactory(List<String> l ){
        this.list = l;
        Thread p= new Producer();
        p.setName("Producer");
        p.start();
        Thread c=new Consumer();
        c.setName("Consumer");
        c.start();
    }
}

public class ProducerConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        ThreadFactory pc = new ThreadFactory(l);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.